# How to add ParseUI to a swift project

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm building an app with Parse.com. I added the following frameworks:

I copied across

```
Parse.framework
Bolts.framework
```

and added the following frameworks in Build phases:

```
audiotoolbox.framework
cfnetwork.framework
coregraphics.framework
corelocation.framework
libz.dylib
mobilecoreservices.framework
quartzcore.framework
security.framework
storekit.framework
systemconfiguration.framework
libsqlite3.dylib
```

In my bridging header I have

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

The app is working but now I want to use ParseUI so I added the following to my podfile and did a pod install:

```
pod 'ParseUI'
```

I then added the following to my view controller

```
var logInController = PFLogInViewController()
logInController.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(logInController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier "PFLoginViewController"
```

Where am I going wrong? Must I add anything to the bridging header? I have the frameworks added in Xcode as well as through the pod file.

When I add #import `<ParseUI/ParseUI.h>` to the bridging header I get the error 
`Type 'MEssageCollectionViewController' does not conform to protocol 'PFLoginViewControllerDelegate'` on the line `logInController.delegate = self`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following line to `Bridging-Header.h`

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

After you add that, you'll need to add the following delegate functions to your class. They can be found [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFLogInViewControllerDelegate.html).

```
– logInViewController:shouldBeginLogInWithUsername:password:
– logInViewController:didLogInUser:
– logInViewController:didFailToLogInWithError:
– logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn:
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I will try again and post the error if it doesn't work

Comment: When I add the import like you suggested I get the error Type 'MEssageCollectionViewController' does not conform to protocol 'PFLoginViewControllerDelegate' on the line logInController.delegate = self

Comment: That's an entirely different error. That's because you have to add the `PFLoginViewControllerDelegate` functions. I'll edit my answer.