# How to show Parse array in a TableView in Swift Xcode 6.4

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

How can I put objects array inside theArray in order to display results in tableView? since the query is asynchronous, I can't simply say theArray = objects. So, how can I intercept the array out from the query?

EDIT:

Ashish answer solved the problem, but I had to change the code a bit due to Xcode suggests.

now, I tried to unwrap this because I needed to,

```
var new = object.objectId
println("first: \(new)")
if let tryToUnwrap = new as? NSString {
println("second: \(tryToUnwrap)")
}
```

I downCast to NSString because in Swift string is not a warning: cast from String? to unrelated type'NSString' always fails

code works, but what does it means? how could I get rid of this?

```
import UIKit

import Parse


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var theArray : [PFObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //MARK: PFQUERY
        //***********************************************************************
        var query = PFQuery(className:"TestObject")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

                // Do something with the found objects

                self.theArray = (objects as? [PFObject])!

                if self.theArray.count > 0 {
                    self.myTableView.reloadData()
                }

                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {

//                        var new = object.objectId
//                        println("first: \(new)")
//                        
//                        if let tryToUnwrap = new as? NSString {
//                            println("second: \(tryToUnwrap)")
//                        }

                        println("here the object id: \(object.objectId)")

                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
        //***********************************************************************
        //        if let string = dict.objectForKey("SomeKey") as? String {
        //            // If I get here, I know that "SomeKey" is a valid key in the dictionary, I correctly
        //            // identified the type as String, and the value is now unwrapped and ready to use.  In
        //            // this case "string" has the type "String".
        //            println(string)
        //        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    //MARK: UITableViewDataSource (required to conform to UITableViewDataSource)
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theArray.count

    }

    //MARK: UITableViewDataSource (required to conform to UITableViewDataSource)
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell : TaskCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! TaskCell

        cell.objectIdLabel.text = theArray[indexPath.row].objectId

        return cell
    }


    //MARK: UITableViewDelegate (not required)
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("section is: \(indexPath.section) row is: \(indexPath.row)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reload the table after getting it.

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"TestObject")
    //        query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            theArray = objects as? [PFObject]
            if theArray.count > 0 {
                  myTableView.reloadData()
            }
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fine! updated the question, Xcode forced me to change a bit your code, and now it works! Could you help me with the unWrap warning?

Answer (score 1):

Parse also has it's own viewcontroller PFQueryTableViewController which includes a query that then sets up the cells in your table view. I think this may be useful for your code.

see https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#user-interface-pfquerytableviewcontroller for more information.

Comment: Useful, but when I create a new file / cocoaTouch file, I can't choose PFQueryTableViewController from the classes menu (instead of UITableViewController)

Comment: Have you tried adding #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> to your bridgingheader.h file?

Comment: This post might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708057/how-to-add-parseui-to-a-swift-project

Comment: I added #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> to the bridging file, and dragged ParseUI framework copy if needed too, but still can't get the option. did you ever used that PFQueryTableViewController? how did you win the battle?

Comment: they don't give may instructions there, but I will check the Repo!

Answer (score 1):

for your edit would you want the code:

```
var new = object.objectId
println("first: \(new)")
if let tryToUnwrap:String = new {
println("second: \(tryToUnwrap)")
}
```

Comment: no :( , maybe you forgot a { , but it gives me this issue anyway:  bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type

Comment: great! the edit worked! please, could you explain me my mistake? I thought  down casting to NSString would be the right thing!

Comment: object.objectId returns a value of type "string?" the "if let" then unwraps that optional and sets it to "tryToUnwrap", this is used to check that the value of "new" is not nil. Does this answer your question?

Comment: not sure, because in my mind I can't understand differences between our two solutions if not in syntax :) , let's see : is it something like "since new is of String? type, let's check if it is nil by using the if let" now reading from the right "if new is not nil it will be of String type, and set tryToUnwrap to its value" so this solution should be right for ints too? they are Struct as the Strings, right?

Comment: yes, so you could say "if new != nil { var tryToUnwrap = new as! String }